# Why can't I forward-declare a type in a qualified namespace in C++?

Tags: c++, namespaces, forward-declaration

I am trying to avoid including an auto-generated header (outside of my control), from inside my own headers. I therefore need to forward-declare a type `Type` that lives inside a namespace `nm`, which itself lives in the global namespace. Here is an example of `MyHeader.h`:

```
// My project defines two levels of nested namespaces 
namespace foo { namespace bar {
    namespace nm { struct Type; }
    ...
} }
```

Unfortunately this defines the new namespace `foo::bar::nm` and forward-declares the type `foo::bar::nm::Type`, which is not what I want. Ideally I would be able to forward-declare a type in the qualified namespace `::nm` like this:

```
namespace foo { namespace bar {
    namespace ::nm { struct Type; }
    ...
} }
```

My compiler complains I cannot use a qualified namespace here (using Intel ICC15 with C++11 settings). This forces me to put all such forward declarations at the beginning:

```
namespace nm { struct Type; }
namespace foo { namespace bar {
    ...
} }
```

In my case, this is inconvenient because I need to forward-declare many types and would prefer to do so alongside definitions of my own in various scattered places in my header. A workaround could be to constantly be "closing" and "re-opening" my nested namespace, which is not ideal.

Why can't I forward-declare a type in a qualified namespace ?

Comment: try changing the original namespace class....as far as i can recall, one of my colleagues was putting his own customizations to namespace.....although i could be wrong as he could have been trying to do something else and i mis-understood it..........C++ rules and regulations (standards) would prohibit the declaration you are trying to do but it wil not prohibit you from trying or attempting to customize the standards or definitions as long as they could be..........i knw wat i just said was too convolute but i hope u know what i meant.

Answer (score 3):

Because the C++ standard says so.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real reason I know of. This is just not supported, probably, no one needed it and no one ever requested it. I see the benefit in your particular case, but since the forward declarations are expected to be provided in a separate file, you'd be better off by simply creating your own `*_fwd.h` with all the forward declarations inside it in the single namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can't because it's ambiguous.  If you wrote:

```
extern int foo::bar;
```

Are you forward declaring an `int` named `bar` in namespace `foo`, or are you forward declaring an `int` named `bar` inside the class `foo`?  There's no way for the compiler to know.